# How to use a CVS repository locally?

Tags: version-control, cvs, wincvs

Is it possible to use (Win)CVS as a local repository? I don't need a multi-user configuration with sharing a repository on a server (I've been using WinCVS for years in a team, and it worked fine for us), but just want to keep track of different versions of my project code locally. Anywhere some good documentation or tutorials? Or are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a local CVS repository in any empty directory
on your computer by setting the `CVSROOT` environment variable
to that directory and running the `cvs init` command.

The [CVS manual](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs.html) describes all the CVS concepts and commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using CVS, which is extremely old, and lacks important features, and instead use a more modern DVCS such as Mercurial or git. That way you don't need to setup any server, and you get atomic commits and better branch handling/merging (among lots of other benefits).

Comment: I've been using WinCVS for years and it works fine for me. But I'll have a look at Mercurial and Git. Does they also have a GUI? And what about Plastic SCM?